# Why are my CodeIgniter form values empty when form is submitted?

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, codeigniter

While learning how to use Code Igniter, i have encountered a problem when submitting form values. I'm trying to do an insert if $_POST and redirect to the form if it wasn't successful, but every time i submit the form i see there are no form values in my header. Been unable to figure out what am doing wrong even after going through several related post, would appreciate the help of the experts here. Here's what I'm working with

View: new_product.php

```
<form action="products/new_product" method="POST" role="form">
    <legend>Upload New Item</legend>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Input field">
        <label for="">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Input field">
        <label for="">Category</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category" placeholder="Input field">
        <label for="">Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Input field">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Controller: products.php

```
public function new_product() 
{
    if ($_POST) {
        $data = array(
            'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            //'photo' => $this->input->post('photo'),
            'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
            'price' => $this->input->post('price')
        );
        $this->product->upload_product($data);
        redirect(base_url().'products/');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('header', FALSE);
        $this->load->view('new_product');
        $this->load->view('footer', FALSE);
    }
}
```

Model: product.php

```
function upload_product($data) {
    $this->db->insert('products', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

header recorder during form submission

[image: header information]

Comment: where is your 'csrf_token'?

Comment: I'm sorry, don't know what you are referring to. Please bare with me, I'm a new to Codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this inside your form,

`<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>">`

So your mark up will be like this now,

```
<form action="products/new_product" method="POST" role="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>">
    <legend>Upload New Item</legend>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Input field">
        <label for="">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Input field">
        <label for="">Category</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category" placeholder="Input field">
        <label for="">Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Input field">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. What's the csrf_token for?

Comment: It is a security feature of CI (CodeIgniter) when you are sending form data. It is required. Read more about this [here.](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.. you missed **name** attribute

```
<form action="products/new_product" method="POST" role="form">
    <legend>Upload New Item</legend>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Input field">
        <label for="">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Input field">
        <label for="">Category</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="category" id="category" placeholder="Input field">
        <label for="">Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Input field">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your form should be llike this** (NO name and value attributes given)

```
       <form action="products/new_product" method="POST" role="form">
              <legend>Upload New Item</legend>

             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="">Name</label>
                   <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Input field">
                   <label for="">Description</label>
                   <input type="text" name="description" value="" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Input field">
                  <label for="">Category</label>
                 <input type="text" name="category" value="" class="form-control" id="category" placeholder="Input field">
                 <label for="">Price</label>
                  <input type="text" name="price" value="" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Input field">
            </div>

          <button name='submit' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
     </form>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse, `CSRF` will be required but your problem is different I think.
**You have missed to add a `name` property to each of your `input` tags.**

**e.g**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="first_name" placeholder="Input field">
```